# Using attr_accessible in a join model with has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, join, has-many-through, attr-accessible

I have a USER that creates a COMPANY and become an EMPLOYEE in the process. The employees table has an `:user_id` and a `:company_id`.

```
class User
has_many :employees
has_many :companies, :through => :employees

class Employee
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company
attr_accessible :active

class Company
has_many :employees
has_many :users, :through => employees
```

Pretty basic. But here's the thing, the resource EMPLOYEE has other attributes than its foreign keys, like the boolean `:active`. I would like to use `attr_accessible`, but this causes some problems. The attribute `:user_id` is set right, but `:company_id` is nil.

```
@user.companies << Company.new(...)
Employee id:1 user_id:1 company_id:nil
```

So my question is: if `:user_id` is set right, despite it is not an `attr_accessible`, why `:company_id` isn't set right just the same? It shouldn't be an `attr_accessible`.

I'm using Rails 3.0.8, and have also tested with 3.0.7.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of bits working together here.

You definitely want to use attr_accessible on all models.  (Google "hack rails mass assignment" and read the [Rails Guide on mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment).)

Once you add attr_accessible to a model, *all* assignments from hashes (mass assignments) are disabled except those you explicitly allow. However, you can still assign values directly, one at a time.

Foreign keys seem like a good thing to exclude from mass assignment, so don't list them in attr_accessible.

The .create and .build methods are not using mass assignment so they can set the value of *one* foreign key association. If there are several associations, as best I can tell, you'll have to set all but the first separately.

Finally, the actual IDs for the foreign keys are created by the database, not by ActiveRecord. So you'll either have to create parent and child records simultaneously, or you'll have to save the child first before you can assign the foreign key in the parent. Otherwise there is no ID available for the assignment.

It's not clear to me from your example how Employee is getting instantiated. But since the Employee belongs to both User and Company, I think something like this might work, assuming @user already exists:

```
company  = @user.companies.create(..) # fills in company.user_id and saves to DB
employee = @user.employees.build(..)  # fills in employee.user_id but does NOT save yet
employee.company = company            # fills in employee.company_id
employee.save                         # now save to DB
```

Comment: how do test for something like this in RSpec? consider `User` with `has_many :roles` and `has_many :accounts, through: :roles`. Say you have `attr_accessible` disabled on `roles.user_id` and `roles.account_id` and `roles.role`. I can't visualize how you would test in Rspec for role. How would you create a role and attach it to an account and a user?

Comment: Mohamad, it depends what you want to test. If you want to confirm that role cannot be mass assigned, you can use a model test like Michael Hartl's [example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code:attr_accessible_user_id_test) (requires Rails 3.2) and/or an integration test like the one I suggest [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262993/rails-integration-test-against-page-modification-hack/10342951#10342951). To "create a role and attach it to an account and a user" you will use standard ActiveRecord commands in the test, or, more likely, FactoryGirl.

Answer (score 0):

The company_id is nil simply because the Company hasn't been saved to the database yet - Company.new simply creates the object in memory without saving it yet.

If you do:

```
@user.companies << Company.create(..)
```

or

```
@user.companies << Company.first
```

They should both work. There's even a shorter method which I think should work too:

```
@user.companies.create(..)
```

It all depends at which point you want to save the association. In some cases, it may be better not to save the employee and company models straight away, and instead wait for when the parent model (User) is saved. In which case you can use:

```
@user.companies.build(..)
```

(which is similar to the code in your example).

In terms of your `active` boolean attribute on the Employee model, if this is a column in the database, you don't need to explicitly declare `attr_accessible` for it - it'll be accessible by default.

Comment: Frankie, thank you for taking the time to help me.

I have used:
    @user.companies.create()
and the error was just the same. The company instance is saved to the database, but when it comes to employee, ActiveRecord complains that Company should not be blank.

I didn't tried, whatsoever, that other sugestion of yours:
    @user.companies << Company.create()

In Employee model, I can use validations on company_id, like presence. But it was very clear to me that it should be an attr_accessible. When I use it on company_id, both create and << (with Company.new) works. An both fail when I don't.

Comment: I have also tried @user.companies << Company.create(), while :company_id is not an attr_accessible. The failure is just the same. Company can't be blank, so the instance company is saved, but not the employee.
When :company_id is set to be accessible, the three ways work:
create, << Company.new and << Company.create.

Comment: Hi. Firstly, you don't need to declare any attributes as attr_accessible - they're all accessible by default.

Comment: Secondly, if you call @user.companies.create(..) that will create a new company (ie save it to the DB), and also initialize (but not save) a new Employee object which joins both the user and company together and return this object.  Whereas @user.companies << Company.create(..) will create and save both the company and the employee records. If you read through http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many you'll see all the different options.

Comment: If I use attr_accessible for the two foreign key attributes, then using an f.association :user in a @company form (or vice versa), then ActiveRecord only assigns one foreign key attribute as described above. If I omit the attr_accessible declaration (it is redundant as mentioned above), then it works fine. I don't see why declaring or not declaring attr_accessible for the foreign keys should make a difference - I expected ActiveRecord to save the Company, get it's ID, and set this on the Employee along with the existing ID of the User...