# Rails integration test against page modification hack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using Capybara 1.1.2, Rails 3.1.3, rspec-rails 2.9.0, and Ruby 1.9.3p0.

Assume an app with standard and account_admin users. A standard user can create another standard user, but a standard user cannot create an account_admin user.

Of course the UI does not give the standard user the option of creating an account admin. But 30 seconds with Firebug and the user can re-write the HTML so it submits a POST request to create an account_admin.

How do I test that my app prevents this kind of simple hack?

The normal standard user test looks like this:

```
context "when standard user is signed in" do

  before do
    login_as standard_user
    visit users_path       # go to index
    click_link('Add user') # click link like user would
  end

  describe "when fields are filled in" do

    let(:new_email) { "new_user@example.com" }

    before do
      fill_in "Email", with: new_email
      fill_in "Password", with: "password"
      fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "password"
      choose "Standard user" # radio button for Role
    end

    it "should create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end

  end

end
```

Is there a way to "fool" the test into taking a value not allowed on the form?  I tried treating the radio button like a text field, but Capybara rejects it as a non-existent field:

```
fill_in "Role", with: "account_admin" # doesn't work
```

Direct modification of the params hash doesn't work either:

```
params[:role] = "account_admin" # doesn't work
```

Do I have to write this more like a controller test, with a direct call to `post :create`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara author jnicklas confirmed [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ruby-capybara/aMnVRN9ooZc/9f4lUASeoaYJ) that Capybara cannot make an app do things that are not available from the UI. He recommends controller tests for authorization.

However request specs written in RSpec *without* using Capybara syntax do allow direct use of HTML verbs (and some additional helpers) as outlined in the [RSpec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-9/docs/request-specs/request-spec) and [Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) docs.  So rather than Capybara's `fill_in` and `click_link` directives and the `page` object, you can use an attribute hash, verbs like `get`, `post`, `post_via_redirect`, and the `response.body` object. It's similar to a controller test, but you're using Rails' routing to choose the appropriate controller action based on the path provided. Here is an example of the latter technique:

```
describe "when standard user attempts to create account_admin user" do

  let(:standard_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:standard_user) }

  let(:attr) { { email: "account_admin@example.com",
                 password: "password",
                 password_confirmation: "password",
                 role: "account_admin" }
              }

  before do
    login_as standard_user
    get new_user_path
  end

  it "should not create a account_admin user" do
    lambda do
      post users_path, user: attr
    end.should_not change(User, :count)
  end

  describe "after user posts invalid create" do
    before { post_via_redirect users_path, user: attr }

    # redirect to user's profile page
    it { response.body.should have_selector('title', text: 'User Profile') }
    it { response.body.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'not authorized') }
  end

end
```